# react-apollo resolve missing fields

Tags: graphql, react-apollo

Let's say I have this `books` query that return 2 records and stored in local cache.

```
query Books {
  books {
    author
    title
  }
}

'Book:1': {
  author: 'Foo',
  title: 'Book 1'
}

'Book:2': {
  author: 'Bar',
  title: 'Book 2'
}
```

When I have another book query as below to get detail of the book, does react-apollo going to fetch missing fields to server or it will return what ever in the cache for that record? Assuming the default fetchPolicy is used (cache-first)

```
query Book {
  book {
    author
    title
    publisher
    publishedAt
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will query the server to fetch the missing fields.